# How to change color of icon and text once clicked or hovering?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5, styling

I'm new to coding and working on project right now. I currently have a side Navbar and I'm trying to get the icon and text to change color when I either hover over it, or once I click on that route, (for example, if I click on Home) it'll stay blue, until I click on another link, and keeps it blue while I'm hovering over other links.

This is my code for my side navBar :

```
const Navbar = ({ handleClick, isLoggedIn, email }) => (
  <div className="wrapper">
    <nav
      className="navbar navbar-expand d-flex flex-column align-item-center-start"
      id="sidebar"
    >
      <a href="/" className="navbar-brand text-light mt-2">
        <div className="display-6 font-weight-bold">
          <span>SPODify +</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <ul className="navbar-nav d-flex flex-column w-100 mt-4">
        <li className=" h-25 nav-item border-bottom">
          <a href="/" className="nav-link text-light pl-4">
            <i className="bi bi-house-door "></i>
           HOME
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className="h-25  nav-item border-bottom">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link text-light ">
            <i className="bi bi-search"></i>
            SEARCH
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item h-10 border-bottom">
          <a href="/show" className="nav-link text-light ">
            <i className="bi bi-rainbow"></i>
            PODCASTS
          </a>
        </li>

        <li className="nav-item h-25 border-bottom">
          <a href="#" className="nav-link text-light pl-4">
            <i className="bi bi-collection"></i>
            YOUR LIBRARY
          </a>
        </li>

        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <>
            <li className="nav-item h-25 border-bottom">
              <a href="/login" className="nav-link text-light pl-4">
                <i className="bi bi-person-circle"></i>
                {email}
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item h-25 border-bottom">
              <a
                href="#"
                onClick={handleClick}
                className="nav-link text-light pl-4"
              >
                LOGOUT
              </a>
            </li>
          </>
        ) : (
          <li className="nav-item h-25 border-bottom">
            <a href="/login" className="nav-link text-light pl-4">
              LOGIN
            </a>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <div>
          <Home email={email} />{" "}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>WELCOME, SIGN UP</h1>
          <Signup />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I tried to achieve this by adding this to my CSS file:

```
nav a.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

But this just makes the entire section blue :

[image: This is what my navbar currently looks like]

Any tips on how I can change **ONLY** the icon and text when I hover over it and once I click on the link? Thanks in advance!

For reference, this is what I'm trying to achieve:

**Currently clicked on Home link and hovering over Guests that's why it's both a different color**

[image: Currently clicked on Home link and hovering over Guests that's why it's both a different color]

Answer (score 2):

Your on the right way. To change the color of the text and icon you'll need to change `background-color` to `color` this css:

```css
nav a.nav-link:hover {
  color: blue; 
}
```

#### Example:

```css
a:hover{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>My Test</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For the active part (once you clicked) you need to add an extra class for that. (example: `.active`). Then you can style it the same way as when you are hovering it:

```
a:hover,
a.active{
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: changing it to color actually doesnt do anything to the link now

Comment: can you provide your whole CSS? I think it could be an inheritance problem.

Comment: I actually fixed it by wrapping both icon and text inside a span tag and adding :hover to it! Thank you!

Comment: btw do I add the class = active on the ahref or is this a CSS style like :hover?

Comment: no, sadly `.active`isn't a pseudoclass: (More about that here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) you have to add that class manually. I don't know much about react, but i think there will be a good router package that will handle the classes and routing for you.